# How to log error record in a sql server store procedure and commit rest of the successful record

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

in my sql server stored procedure, I am processing more than million records. For improving performance, I am processing records after splitting all the records in different batches.

Example : if i am processing 10,000 records then my logic picks up 1000 records at a time, apply business logic and apply the result to database and commit the transaction.

In my situation, when one of the record out of those 1000 records has a error, i want to log the error record and process rest of the records and issue a commit for successfully processed record.

how can i achieve this ?

....